# Line Chart in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, chart

I need a plugin or related which displays a line chart easily. I googled it, but nothing seems what I need.

I have a K's Ripley table generated with R, which has one column with distance and other columns with the result of the algorithm. I just need set the X variable and several Y in order to asset the results. The R plots don't suites me because I need remove several rows first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only chart-type displays I know are the use of Pie Charts and Histograms in QGIS which are classed as diagrams based on a certain attribute. I do not think there is a plugin at the moment which can convey line charts.

An alternative option (if you're familiar with **R**) is to install **R** as a standalone software and [import the data](http://www.statmethods.net/input/importingdata.html) obtained from QGIS as a csv file. You can then add and modify the script mentioned here to create line charts:

http://www.statmethods.net/graphs/line.html

Hope this helps.